# how to send request and response from restapi in seeddms using php

Tags: php

I am working on my project with document management system and i struck at seeddms configuration in my ubuntu Os ,how can I get post request and response using seeddms restapi using slim to upload  documents
or
how to upload documents to seeddms using php programming